# client GUI not updating when server sends a message

Tags: java

I have a interface that all my messages implement. When sending a serialized message via an ObbjectOutputStream the message appears to be passing based on println() statements, however the client gui does not get updated.The program has a gameloop thread that has an infinite loop to repaint the program. The program does update when pass messages through a bufferedreader.
thanks for your help!

Here is the code for when the message gets sent:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("released");
        //released = true;
        world.getSerArrow().move();
        ArrowReleased arrowReleased = new ArrowReleased(world.getSerArrow());
        ObjectOutputStream output = server.getSocketThread().getOutput();
        try {
            output.writeObject(arrowReleased);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the code to read it in:

```
    public class ClientThread extends Thread {

private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader reader;
private PrintWriter out;
private Person person;
private ServerBowAndArrow arrow;
private ObjectInputStream input;

public ClientThread(Socket socket, Person person, ServerBowAndArrow arrow) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.person = person;
    this.arrow = arrow;
}

public PrintWriter getOut() {
    return out;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        input = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        Messages msg = (Messages) input.readObject();
        msg.perform();

        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            person.setX(Integer.valueOf(inputLine));

            person.setY(Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()));

            arrow.setX(Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()));
            arrow.setY(Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()));
        }

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

And this is the perform method that should happen:

```
    @Override
public void perform() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    int x1 = arrow.getX1();
    int x2 = arrow.getX2();
    arrow.setX1(x1 + 100);
    arrow.setX2(x2 + 100);
}
```

Comment: Where does perform get called? Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I'd have a write and read queue, where outgoing messages get added to the write queue and some other thread writes the contents to the socket; another thread would read the messages from the socket and place them on the read queue, which another thread would then process, this way, you can change the way read/writes physically occur, without effecting the rest of the program

Comment: it gets called in the run method right after it receives the message. it is in the above code.